# git How to merge a branch into the master branch by completely overwriting master branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I started work on the **master** branch. Almost one year ago, I created another branch **dev** in which I made some changes. From that time on I continued work on dev branch. Now I want to merge dev into master which results in lot of conflicts. I want to merge dev into master by overwriting master branch's contents i.e. for any conflict that arises I want to keep dev branch's version of the code. How can it be done ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll want to use a "merge using theirs" strategy, which is set using the -X flag

```
git checkout master
git merge -X theirs dev
```

Comment: The problem with this, for me, is that it makes ALL the history from the common commit (i.e. on the dev branch) become the history on the master branch. What if you want the new merged commit to have as its immediate parent (i.e. on the MASTER branch) the common commit?

Answer (score 6):

You can specify [the strategy option](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) with `-X` switch:

```
git checkout master
git merge -X theirs dev
```

A bit explanation. The `-X theirs` means: Use recursive strategy with the merge but fallback to *their* changes if the strategy **cannot** resolve the conflict.

This is different from `-s ours` (for some reason there's no `-s theirs`) which would be a greedy *take ours always* solution to conflicts.

[`git-merge(1)`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html#_merge_strategies) Merge Strategies section provides a deeper explanation on this.

Comment: @hrehman the strategy option. Added a link for further reference.

Comment: Be careful here, `-X ours` or `-X theirs` is quite different from `-s ours`.  There is no `-s theirs`.  It sounds like `-X theirs` is what the OP wants so I believe this is the correct answer (and upvoting it).

Comment: @torek Thanks. I also edited the answer to explain a bit further.

Answer (score 2):

You can force a push into master with all your commits

```
git push -f origin master
```

Answer (score 1):

As [Paulo Bu noted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24921215/1256452), git provides different methods for this when you want a merge with an "ours" approach, but only one "out of the box" when you want a merge with a "theirs" approach.  It's worth illustrating the two by example:

```
$ git merge -s ours deadbranch  # merge deadbranch and ignore all its code
```

or:

```
$ git merge -X ours livebranch  # merge livebranch but use ours when conflicting
```

Let me also note here that when you use `git merge`, git first finds the "merge base", the point at which the two branches were last in sync:

```
            o - X   <-- master
          /
o - o - B
          \
            o - Y   <-- otherbranch
```

Here `B` represents the commit that is the merge-base, `X` is the tip of your branch (`master`), and `Y` is the tip of the other branch.  What git will do is diff `B` vs `X` and `B` vs `Y`.

Let's say that in "our" branch, `master`, we have files `unchanged`, `no-conflicts`, `conflict`, and `removed`.  These names are with respect to what happened in the other two branches.

File `unchanged` is unchanged in the to-be-merged branch (that is, the diff from `B` to `Y` shows nothing at all for file `unchanged`).  `git merge` never touches it, so nothing changes no matter what arguments we give to `git merge`.

The other files have some changes in `master` and/or the other branch.

File `no-conflicts` has one change in `master` at the top, and one change in the other branch at the bottom.  These two changes do not conflict.  `git merge -s recursive` will combine the changes, whether or not you use the `-X ours` option.  However, `git merge -s ours` will discard their change, keeping our version of file `no-conflicts`.  For *this* case, the result is different.

File `conflict` has one change in master at the top of the file, and a different change in the other branch also at the top.  (The changes could be anywhere, they just have to overlap.  "At the top" makes it overlap.)  That means these changes conflict.  Using `git merge -s recursive`, you'll get a complaint and have to resolve the conflict.  Add `-X ours` and git will take your change, throwing away their change.  Using `git merge -s ours`, git will take your change and throw away their change—so for *this* case, the result is the same.

File `removed` has no change in `master` but is removed in the other branch.  In this case, `git merge -s recursive` will remove the file, whether or not you use `-X ours`.  However, `git merge -s ours` will ignore the removal.

In short, the difference between `-s ours` and `-s recursive -X ours` is that with the former, git *completely ignores the diff from `B` to `Y`*; with the latter, git attempts to combine the diffs `B`-to-`X` (ours) and `B`-to-`Y` (theirs), but in the case of a conflict during combining, it picks the `B`-to-`X` change.

With `-X theirs` (which is really `-s recursive -X theirs`), git attempts to combine the diffs, and in the case of conflict, chooses the `B`-to-`Y` change over the `B`-to-`X` change.

---

It is possible to achieve the equivalent of `-s theirs` even though git does not have this built in.  To do this, use `git merge --no-commit otherbranch`, then `git rm -rf .` from the top level to remove the resulting merge (with or without conflicts), then `git checkout otherbranch -- .` from the top level to re-populate the tree and index based on `otherbranch`.  Then simply `git commit` the result.  It's pretty rare to want this, though, which is why git does not have it as a built in strategy.